# Pass hidden field in rails

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails

I have a table for tours (and a table for toursights that allows for multiple sights for a single tour).  In my new/create form, I'm trying to add multiple sights to a tour.  The way I've done it is using jQuery, "joined" all the values of the input forms as a single string of sights and set that as the value of a single hidden field.  I'm lost as to how to expand it once it hits the model and then add each one into the table.  Any ideas?

tour.js

```
  $("#new_tour").on("submit", function(event){
     event.preventDefault();
     var inputs = $.map($(".sight_field"), function(input_element){
        return input_element.value;
     });
     var inputs_joined = inputs.join("|");
     $(":hidden").val(inputs_joined);
});
```

portion of index.html.erb

```
<div class="input_fields_wrap">
   <button class="add_field_button">Add More Sights</button>
      <%= f.label :sights %>
    <input type="text" class="sight_field">
</div>
<div>   
<%= f.hidden_field :sights %>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

With rails you don't need to do such things.

Create a proper form around your fields and just let it submit. Within your controller all variables will be in the params-hash. E.g.

```
params[:sights]
```

If it gets complicated, you can have things like

```
<input type="hidden" name="seeing[paris][sight]" value="fine" />
<input type="hidden" name="seeing[munich][sight]" value="fantastic" />
```

which would result to in the controller

```
params[:seeing][:paris][:sight]
params[:seeing][:munich][:sight]
```

If this is for some reason not feasible, you can also do something like this:

```
<input type="hidden" name="sights" value="fine, fantastic, ok" />
```

And in the controller

```
all_sights = params[:sights].split(',')
```

which will be an array of your sights.

Comment: Andreas, do you mean I don't need to "join"?  Just have the sights as a hash in the single hidden field and rails will understand that I'm trying to have multiple of that attribute?

Comment: I've updated my answer to your comment. I know, that you mean to put those things into one value, but try it this way, if you will. It is much more clear and you have order and readability right away.